# Add custom binary to containers PATH in Docker?

Tags: linux, mount, docker

I would like to add a custom binary executable to one of containers. I have made it on my machine and try to add it. At first I thought about mounting some directory as `/tmp/foo` and just copy it to `/usr/bin/`. Not very nice but should do the trick. To do so I defined following volume mounting in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
volumes:
  - ./var/bin/:/tmp/bin/
```

and following command in `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN ls /tmp/bin

RUN cp /tmp/bin/wkhtmltoimage /usr/local/bin/ && cp /tmp/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/local/bin/
```

As you can see I already added listing directory to check if anything's there and I got

```
ls: cannot access /tmp/bin: No such file or directory
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c ls /tmp/bin' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Now, there are two questions:
1. Why this directory is not visible in the container's command line? The other mounts are available...
2. How can I achieve this goal "properly"? So that the binary would be copied/set once during image build and wouldn't require a mapping on every container run?

Comment: Why don't you use a `COPY src dest` command in the Dockerfile to copy the executable to /usr/local/bin (instead of using volumes + `RUN cp....`).

Comment: It's not an issue with COPY, RUN or wathever... the problem I was having was that the mount takes place later than this build. Luckily I got the answer already.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the same question was asked and answered on Stack Overflow (where it probably fits better anyway):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47818862/add-a-custom-binary-to-docker-container-path